# Como minificar o CSS/Javascript automaticamente no ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, minificação

Utilizo o Visual studio 2017, minha aplicação roda em ASP.NET MVC5 (Razor), existe um modo de minificar todos os arquivos que eu escolher no momento do "publish" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem o Bundle do framework. Dentro do seu folder `App_Start` crie uma classe `BundleConfig.cs` e adicione:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //para javascript, você pode fazer vários includes para o mesmo arquivo "scripts"        
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include("~/seuJs.js"));
    //para Css
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/seuCss.css"));

    //EnableOptimizations força a minificação mesmo em desenvolvimento, serve para fazer teste se esta minificado corretamente.
    //BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Depois é apenas registrar ele no seu `Application_Start`:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

No seu .cshtml é necessário mandar renderizar o javascript ou css:

```
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
</body>
```

Comment: Certinho ! obrigado